# Good System monitoring tool with AWS Auto-Scaling Service

Tags: amazon-ec2, monitoring, autoscaling

I am finding a good System monitoring tool using with AWS Auto scaling service. What i need is when My new instance is launched the monitoring Agent should be registered itself automatically to the Monitoring server. I have tried [nagios](http://www.nagios.org), [sensu](http://www.sonian.com) for testing but there is no more facility i have found that provides agent to be auto register on monitoring server. There are other couple of suggestions like HypricHQ, OpenNMS but I failed to find that flexibility. Is there any other tool which provides that facility?

Comment: This sentence is unclear "new instance is launched the monitoring Agent should be registered itself automatically to the Monitoring server". Is the new instance an agent, or a server, or what?

Comment: David: every new instance is an agent. Monitoring Server is not supposed to auto scale.

Comment: Maybe a better topic for serverfault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some R&D on this topic, i go with [CloudWatch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) service provided by AWS. What I have done is made my own monitoring program which fetch data from AWS CloudWatch.

Answer (score 1):

Zabbix uses an active agent capable of [autoregistering](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/discovery/auto_registration) whithin zabbix server, other systems that use the same phylosophy may be capable of the same. But you have to find a way to remove stale downscaled servers

In traditional server centric monitoring systems an external script should be used to get from aws api the server list and perhaps roles of these servers via tags like [the one in shinken](https://github.com/shinken-monitoring/mod-import-aws)

There's a way to get in sync monitoring servers each time you scale or downscale. Autoscaling in amazon can post SNS notifications when it launch or destroy machines, you can create a topic in SNS and assing the [autoscaling notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/ASGettingNotifications.html) and put a HTML endpoint able to "refresh" the monitoring server hosts lists.